# Wordpress contact form 7 conditional logic pdf generation

Tags: wordpress, pdf, conditional-statements, pdf-generation, contact-form-7

I've built a multi-step contact form 7 questionnaire which uses a conditional logic plugin to help with some of the sections.

I've added the problem area below, it's one part of the form where the user makes a selection and is offered one of four additional sections depending on their choice.

This all works well. In the message body of the email that is sent this section displays correctly. The remaining 3 groups are hidden and don't display. Great.

But in the PDF that is generated using other WordPress plugins we have tested unfortunately all the group tags are displayed.

Is there any way I can structure the conditional logic differently or is there an alternative solution?

Any help or additional information, please ask.

Thanks

**Contact Form 7**

```html
<div>
    <h3>My Choice - Step 4</h3>
</div>
<div>Select 'ONE' procedure [radio procedure use_label_element "Mesh Tape" "Colposuspension" "Natural Tissue Sling" "Urethra Bulking Agent Injection"]</div>
<div>

[group mesh-selected clear_on_hide]
    Statement 1 [text mesh-mesh1 use_label_element placeholder"Reason Why"]
    Statement 2 [text mesh-colp1 use_label_element placeholder"Why I'm not"]
    Statement 3 [text mesh-sling1 use_label_element placeholder"Why I'm not"]
    Statement 4 [text mesh-ureth1 use_label_element placeholder"Why I'm not"]
[/group]
[group colp-selected clear_on_hide]
    Statement 1 [text colp-colp2 placeholder"Reason Why"]
    Statement 2 [text colp-mesh2 placeholder"Why I'm not"]
    Statement 3 [text colp-sling2 placeholder"Why I'm not"]
    Statement 4 [text colp-ureth2 placeholder"Why I'm not"]
[/group]
[group sling-selected clear_on_hide]
    Statement 1 [text sling-sling3 placeholder"Reason Why"]
    Statement 2 [text sling-colp3 placeholder"Why I'm not"]
    Statement 3 [text sling-mesh3 placeholder"Why I'm not"]
    Statement 4 [text sling-ureth3 placeholder"Why I'm not"]
[/group]
[group ureth-selected clear_on_hide]
    Statement 1 [text ureth-ureth4 placeholder"Reason Why I'm"]
    Statement 2 [text ureth-sling4 placeholder"Why I'm not"]
    Statement 3 [text ureth-colp4 placeholder"Why I'm not"]
    Statement 4 [text ureth-mesh4 placeholder"Why I'm not"]
[/group]
</div>
```

**Conditional Logic**

```
show [mesh-selected] if [procedure] equals "Mesh Tape"
show [colp-selected] if [procedure] equals "Colposuspension"
show [sling-selected] if [procedure] equals "Natural Tissue Sling"
show [ureth-selected] if [procedure] equals "Urethral Bulking Agent Injection"
```

**PDF Form Layout**

```
MY CHOICE
---------
Chosen Procedure: [procedure][mesh-selected]
[mesh-mesh1]
[mesh-colp1]
[mesh-sling1]
[mesh-ureth1]
[/mesh-selected][colp-selected]
[colp-mesh2]
[colp-colp2]
[colp-sling2]
[colp-ureth2]
[/colp-selected][sling-selected]
[sling-mesh3]
[sling-colp3]
[sling-sling3]
[sling-ureth3]
[/sling-selected][ureth-selected]
[ureth-mesh4]
[ureth-colp4]
[ureth-sling4]
[ureth-ureth4]
[/ureth-selected]
```

**PDF Screenshot**

Shows some random characters that were entered into one field section & the [group][/group] tags that are unfortunately displaying:

[image]

Comment: Which plugin you using to create PDF?

Comment: @Earid https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/send-pdf-for-contact-form-7/ & a couple of others.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional tags are closed on your form structure like this:

```
[group group-394][/group]
```

But in the PDF you need to close tags like this:

```
[group-394][/group-394]
```

This way you can hide separate texts along with the question.